# Highcharts.js question: is it possible to add blank space from the left and right side of chart that will be visible only during panning?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I develop a project using Highstock.js library. I need to display blank space (let's say equal 1 day (86400000 ms) by x axis) from the most left and right parts of chart that will be visible only during panning to the most left or right (https://prnt.sc/lyqshz). I do not need to set chart  margins (https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.margin).
I tried to solve this issue by setting 'min' and 'max' of xAxis as :

```
xAxis: {
    min: ohlc[0].x - ONE_DAY_MS,
    max: ohlc[ohlc.length - 1].x + ONE_DAY_MS,
},
```

but that didn't work.
Please advise if it is possible to implement that and how it can be done.
Thanks!

Here is full code of example:

```
var ohlc = JSON.parse(ohlcStringified),
    volume = JSON.parse(volumeStringified);
var ONE_DAY_MS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        panning: true,
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Chart'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1,
        enabled: false
    },

    navigator: {
        enabled: false,
        height: 0
    },

    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        min: ohlc[0].x - ONE_DAY_MS,
        max: ohlc[ohlc.length - 1].x + ONE_DAY_MS,
    },
    yAxis: [{
        height: '60%'
    }, {
        top: '60%',
        height: '40%',
        offset: 0
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        id: 'candlestick',
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: ohlc,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false,
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        id: 'volume',
        name: 'Volume',
        data: volume,
        yAxis: 1,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false,
        }
    }]
});

function chartZoomIn(chart) {
    var min = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min;
    var max = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max;

    var diff = max - min;
    var step = 0.05 * diff;
    var newMin = min + step;
    var newMax = max - step;

    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(newMin, newMax);
}

function chartZoomOut(chart) {
    var min = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min;
    var max = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max;
    var candlestickXData = chart.get('candlestick').xData;
    var zoomInMin = candlestickXData[0];
    var zoomInMax = candlestickXData[candlestickXData.length - 1];

    var diff = max - min;
    var step = 0.05 * diff ;
    var newMin = min - step;
    var newMax = max + step;

    if (newMin <= zoomInMin || newMax >= zoomInMax) {
        chart.zoomOut();
    } else {
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(newMin, newMax);
    }
}
$('.zoom-in').click(function() {
    chartZoomIn(chart);
})
$('.zoom-out').click(function() {
    chartZoomOut(chart);
})
$('.full-zoom-out').click(function() {
    chart.zoomOut();
})
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ogorobets/82adzfhL/25/

**Update 1:**

There is an option 'overscroll' for xAxis (https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.overscroll). It allows to display empty space to the most right of the chart. But it still isn't clear how to implement same behaviour for case when user pan to the most left of the chart. I tried to solve latter issue by setting 'minPadding' parameter to 0.2 but it doesn't solve the issue.

```
xAxis: {
    minPadding: 0.2,
    overscroll: 60 * 60 * 1000
},
```

Here is live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ogorobets/82adzfhL/33/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show additional empty space on the left and right of the plot area you can add points with `null` value. Check the demo posted below.

**Code:**

```
var data = [
  [1542292200000, 191.41],
  [1542378600000, 193.53],
  [1542637800000, 185.86],
  [1542724200000, 176.98],
  [1542810600000, 176.78],
  [1542983400000, 172.29],
  [1543242600000, 174.62],
  [1543329000000, 174.24],
  [1543415400000, 180.94],
  [1543501800000, 179.55],
  [1543588200000, 178.58],
  [1543847400000, 184.82],
  [1543933800000, 176.69],
  [1544106600000, 174.72],
  [1544193000000, 168.49],
  [1544452200000, 169.6],
  [1544538600000, 168.63],
  [1544625000000, 169.1],
  [1544711400000, 170.95],
  [1544797800000, 165.48],
  [1545057000000, 163.94],
  [1545143400000, 166.07],
  [1545229800000, 160.89],
  [1545316200000, 156.83],
  [1545402600000, 150.73],
  [1545661800000, 146.83],
  [1545834600000, 157.17]
];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  data.unshift([
    data[0][0] - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    null
  ]);

  data.push([
    data[data.length - 1][0] + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    null
  ]);
}

console.log(data);
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 0
  },
  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: data,
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2
    }
  }]
});
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4ztrm7cg/1/

Comment: It is correct solution for case when you don't have indicators displayed for this chart. But in my case I have a number of indicators that should be displayed for chart. Here is live example when you display 'null chart points' and also have SMA and MACD indicators displayed: http://jsfiddle.net/ogorobets/ph12jvx8/50/. In this case SMA and MACD indicators are drawn taking account of null chart points that is not correct. Do you know if there is a way for indicators (SMA and MACD in this case) to not take account of null chart points? Thanks!

Comment: In that case, you can add another series only with null points. Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ue36t9nb/.